# Execute string as C#

Tags: c#

I am checking conditions that could change and so would like to build them in a string and then run that string as C#.

```
//string conditionToCheck = user.Userdetail.Age > 18
string conditionToCheck = "user." + condition.Table + "." + condition.Column + " " + condition.Operator + " " + condition.Value;
if(conditionToCheck)
{
    ConditionsMet = true;
}
```

Is there someway to convert conditionToCheck into C# ?

---

*Background*

I allow a user to create conditions by selecting a table and it's column and then assign and operator of > < == and a value.

Since a user can select any column of any table in the DB i need the code to check the conditions to handle anything.

Comment: You probably could get the values of the operands via reflection, but this really calls for a different approach. **This reeks of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you *actually* trying to solve with this? Why?**

Comment: C# is not for such style of programming. Go to LISP.

Comment: What type is `user`? How many different tables and columns can there be?

Comment: If you need this for DB processing, it is much easier and logically to generate SQL queries, not C#.

Comment: There is " such style of programming" It's called linq expressions. For string compiling you can use Roslyn api but do it with expressions if you can

Comment: Also this seams to be a bad way of protecting you self of injection attacks so if you are not 100% percent sure that you are safe don't use strings

Comment: Check more about expressionvisitor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx This seems match your need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best solution is probably to use the CodeDOM to dynamically compile C# code. After that you can use reflection to dynamically load and execute your compiled assembly and getting the results from the evaluation. I'm not sure if this is the best or the most elegant solution to your problem however.

You can find an example [here](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to solve,

but if you are attempting to dynamically convert text to C#

code maybe you should use a T4 solution:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx